# Parsing input in C

Tags: c, parsing, tokenize

i am trying to parse input from a character buffer `char buf[BUFLEN];`

The input I'm trying to parse is:

```
GET /file.html HTTP/1.3
Host: www.bbc.co.uk
```

I need to store the `GET`, the `/index.html`, `HTTP/1.1` and `www.bbc.co.uk` all into separate variables

What is the best way to parse over this input and separate it into variables?

Thanks

Comment: Do you think your method is not good enough? can you post it?

Comment: Hi, i currently haven't started implementing a method

Comment: There are several options. One would be to use `fgets` to read each line, and `strtok` to parse tokens.

Comment: @JamieDale Try to implement it yourself. If you face a problem, you can ask it here. As a starter you can learn `strtok` or `*scanf` in depth

Comment: `HTTP/1.3` and `HTTP/1.1` are different.

Comment: This site doesn't work like that, read about `strstr()` and `strtok()`, and then write something if it doesn't work, come back. Be careful with `strtok()` because it's not reentrant...